# create ordered sequence of random numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to generate an ordered sequence of random numbers and put them in a table (array or object) like below, but I have no idea how to do it:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 12 |  | 35 |  |  | 63 | 71 |  |
| 8 |  |  | 39 |  | 50 |  | 78 |  |
|  | 15 | 29 |  | 43 | 52 | 66 |  | 85 |

the result I want can be something like below, *I just showed it in a table above to be more readable*, as you see each column represented as a sub array below:

`[[6,8, ],[12, ,15],[ , ,29],[35,39, ],[ , ,43],[ ,50,52],[63, ,66],[71,78, ],[ , ,85]]`

or it can be an object like this, if result is an object each key-value pair represents a column:

`{1:[6,8, ],2:[12, ,15],3:[ , ,29],4:[35,39, ],5:[ , ,43],6:[ ,50,52],7:[63, ,66],8:[71,78, ],9:[ , ,85]}`

here are the rules:

1. column 1 must be from 1 to 9, column 2 must be from 10 to 19 ..., col 9 must be from 80 to 90
2. each column must have at least 1 number
3. numbers in each column must be ordered. but randomly placed.

**Update**

till now I create a sequence of ordered random numbers using this:

```js
const randomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const createSequence = () => {
  const sequence = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
    let column = [];
    while (true) {
      let random;
      if (row == 0) {
        random = randomNumber(1, 9);
      } else {
        random = randomNumber(row * 10, row * 10 + 9);
      }
      if (!column.includes(random)) {
        column.push(random);
      }
      if (column.length >= 3) {
        column = column.sort();
        break;
      }
    }
    sequence.push(column);
  }
  console.log(sequence);
  return sequence;
};
createSequence()
```

using above code I get something like this:

[
[
7,
8,
9
],
[
12,
16,
19
],
[
20,
23,
24
],
[
33,
35,
36
],
[
44,
46,
47
],
[
51,
56,
58
],
[
60,
66,
68
],
[
70,
73,
77
],
[
80,
84,
86
]
]

now I have to remove numbers randomly from the array, to achieve the goal, but I don't know how? any idea or solution (or a completely different approach) is appreciated.

thank you all.

Comment: Hi @ako, please show what you have tried for a bit more clarity on answering

Comment: #3 doesn't make sense to me. must be ordered _and_ randomly placed?

Comment: @Deepak : I have tried something but no close to an answer, as I don't know how to approach it .

Comment: @Kinglish: as you see in the table they numbers in columns are ordered but if we have two numbers they may be in any row in the column like they may be in row 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 or 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of solving a problem like this is figuring out if there's a different representation that would make it easier to solve. Tables are usually arranged as a series of rows. However, treating the table as a series of columns makes solving this easier.

An additional, tricky issue is that the column ranges aren't same for all columns. Most columns have a range of 10 but the first column has a range of 9 and the last column has a range of 11.

The solution here generates values for all cells and then eliminates ~half of them, leaving at least one in each column.

```js
const randRng = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min) + min);

const generateData = (rows, cols, p = 0.5) => {
  const data = [];
  for(let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    const min = c == 0 ? 1 : c * 10;
    const max = c == 0 ? 9 : c == cols - 1 ? min + 10 : min + 9;
    // fill all the cells with unique values
    const set = new Set();
    do {
      set.add(randRng(min, max));
    } while(set.size < rows);
    const sorted = Array.from(set).sort();
    // filter out some of the cells, keep at least one
    const keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
    const values = sorted.map(
      (v, i) => (keep == i || Math.random() < p ? v : null)
    );
    data.push(values);
  }
  return data;
};

const tableFromData = (data) => {
  const table = [];
  // add table header
  table.push('<thead><tr>');
  for(let c = 1; c <= data.length; c++) {
    table.push(`<th>${c}</th>`);
  }
  table.push('</tr></thead>');
  // swap cols/rows and convert to html
  for(let r = 0; r < data[0].length; r++) {
    table.push('<tr>');
    for(let c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
      table.push(`<td>${ data[c][r] ?? "&nbsp;" }</td>`);
    }
    table.push('</tr>');
  }
  return table.join('');
};

const data = generateData(3, 9);
const table = tableFromData(data);
document.querySelector('table').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Note that, since we generate values for all cells and then filter them, distribution is such that first rows will tend to have values towards the beginning of the range, progressing to the last rows having values towards the end of the range.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but with this current implementation there is a good chance that two or more numbers in a column be equal, in my code I check this situation using `column.includes(random)`, if you solve this issue I'll accept your answer, if not, I 'll post the correct answer that I have implemented with the help of your solution.

Comment: @Ako updated to ensure uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

There seems many different ways to approach this, but one way would be to create random numbers and insert them into a list, one at a time, where they would be in order.

To have the 2-d portion of the table it would just be another step while inserting. Sort on the 10's place, then in that index of the array you could insert based on the 1's place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).